# Can I pull raid 5 disk from IBM X365 to put into another X365

Tags: windows-server-2003, raid5

I have an IBM X365 that is sitting in a corner.  It has the same size drives as the IBM X365 that has a failed drive.  Both have Raid 5.  Can I pull drive from the one sitting in the corner and install to replace the failed drive?  I don't want the data from the old one I want it to replace the dead one.

Answer (score 1):

short answer - yes. as long as the drive is the same size and geometry. the fact that it was in a previous RAID array doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you that is what I was hoping the answer would be.  They are the exact same drives in both servers.  Just need to keep this one going for a little while longer